# How do I correctly retrieve, using bash' cut, the first field from a line with only 1 field in a text file?

Tags: cut, gnu-coreutils

In a text file (accounts.txt) with (financial) accounts the sub-accounts are, and need to be, separated by an underscore, looking like this:

```
assets
assets_hh
assets_hh_reimbursements
assets_hh_reimbursements_ff
```

... etc.

Now I want to get specific sub-accounts from specific line numbers, e.g.:
field 3 from line 4:

```
$ lnr=4; fnr=3
$ cut -d $'\n' -f "$lnr" < accounts.txt | cut -d _ -f "$fnr"
reimbursements
$
```

But both fnr=1 and fnr=2 give for the first line, which has only 1 field:

```
$ cut -d $'\n' -f 1 < accounts.txt | cut -d _ -f "fnr"
assets
$
```

which is undesired behaviour.

Now I can get around this by prefixing an underscore to each account and add 1 to each required field number, but this is not an elegant solution.
Am I doing something wrong and/or can this be changed by issuing a different retrieval command?

Comment: What led you to use cut instead of awk?

Comment: Somewhat pedantic but `cut` is not part of, or provided by, `bash`; on Linux it is typically provided by the `coreutils` package.

Comment: Did you mean to use `"fnr"` and not `"$fnr"`?

Comment: @Ignacio I don't 'speak' awk, that's why.

Comment: @anubhava the expected output is 'assets' for fnr=1, empty for other fields, because there is only 1 field.

Comment: @Charles Bailey (1) ok, I stand corrected.

Comment: @Charles (2) Yes sorry, my bad (typo), "$fnr"

Answer (score 2):

Using the `cut -d $'\n' -f "$lnr"` for getting the `lnr-th` line from the file is somewhat strange. More common approach is using `sed`, like:

```
sed -n "${lnr}p" file | cmd ...
```

However, for this the `awk` is better - in one invocation could handle the `lnr` and `fnr` too.

```
file=accounts.txt
lnr=1
fnr=2
awk -F_ -v l=$lnr -v f=$fnr 'NR==l{print $f}' "$file"
```

The above for the all combinations lnr/fnr produces:

```
line                          field1   field2   field3           field4
------------------------------------------------------------------------
assets                        assets
assets_hh                     assets   hh
assets_hh_reimbursements      assets   hh       reimbursements
assets_hh_reimbursements_ff   assets   hh       reimbursements   ff
```

Comment: Using `cut` isn't just strange, it isn't portable. The approach doesn't work with BSD `cut`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Check below solution -

```
cat f
assets
assets_hh
assets_hh_reimbursements
assets_hh_reimbursements_ff
```

Based on your comment try below commands -

```
$ lnr=1; fnr=2
$ echo $lnr $fnr
1 2
$ awk -v lnr=$lnr -v fnr=$fnr  -F'_' 'NR==lnr  {print $fnr}' f
             ###Output is nothing as line 1 column 2 is blank when FS="_"
$ lnr=4;fnr=1
$ echo $lnr $fnr
4 1
$ awk -v lnr=$lnr -v fnr=$fnr  -F'_' 'NR==lnr  {print $fnr}' f
assets
$ lnr=4;fnr=3
$ echo $lnr $fnr
4 3
$ awk -v lnr=$lnr -v fnr=$fnr  -F'_' 'NR==lnr  {print $fnr}' f
reimbursements
```

Comment: The problem is field 2 (doesn't exist) from line 1. lnr=1, fnr=2 still gives 'assets' where it should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to `head|tail` and `read` into an array so it's easier to work with the items:

```
lnr=4
fnr=2
IFS=_ read -r -a arr < <(head -n "$lnr" accounts.txt | tail -n 1)
#note that the array is 0-indexed, so the fieldnumber has to fit that
echo "${arr[$fnr]}"
```

Then you could expand the idea into a more usable function:

```
get_field_from_file() {
    local fname="$1"
    local lnr="$2"
    local fnr="$3"
    IFS=_ read -r -a arr < <(head -n "$lnr" "$fname" | tail -n 1)
    if (( $fnr > ${#arr[@]} )); then
        return 1
    else
        echo "${arr[$fnr]}"
    fi
}

field=$(get_field_from_file "accounts.txt" "4" "2") || echo "no such line or field"
[[ -n $field ]] && echo "field: $field"
```